# Bash script to get privileges difference of files in two directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How can I write a `bash` script on Linux to determine which files in two directories have different permissions?

For example, I have two directories:

`fold1` having two files:

```
 1- file1 (-rw-rw-r--)  
 2- file2 (-rw-rw-r--)
```

`fold2` having same-name files with different permissions:

```
1- file1 (-rwxrwxr-x)  
2- file2 (-rw-rw-r--)
```

I need a script to output the file names that have different permissions,
so the script will print only `file1`

I am currently checking the permissions manually by displaying the files with:

```
for i in `find .`; do ls -l $i ls -l ../file2/$i; done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing `find .` output with: `for i in $(find .)` is going to give you trouble for any filenames with spaces, newlines, or other perfectly normal characters:

```
$ touch "one file"
$ for i in `find .` ; do ls -l $i ; done
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 17:30 one file
ls: cannot access ./one: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
$
```

Since permissions can *also* differ by owner or by group, I think you should include those as well. If you need to include the SELinux security label, the `stat(1)` program makes that easy to get as well via the `%C` directive:

```
for f in * ; do stat -c "%a%g%u" "$f" "../scatman/${f}" |
    sort | uniq -c | grep -q '^\s*1' && echo "$f" is different ; done
```

(Do whatever you want for the `echo` command...)

Example:

```
$ ls -l sarnold/ scatman/
sarnold/:
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 18:00 funky file
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 18:01 second file
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root    0 2012-02-08 18:05 third file

scatman/:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 17:30 funky file
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 18:01 second file
-rw-r--r-- 1 sarnold sarnold 0 2012-02-08 18:05 third file
$ cd sarnold/
$ for f in * ; do stat -c "%a%g%u" "$f" "../scatman/${f}" | sort | uniq -c | grep -q '^\s*1' && echo "$f" is different ; done
funky file is different
third file is different
$
```